# Is it possible to float and stack the items using just CSS?

Tags: css, css-float

I wanted to see if this was possible without using JavaScript and just CSS. I have a list of items in divs.There are some items which are 1/2 the height of others and I want them to stack up. Without adding another container element for the two bits, since I can't change the structure, it is just a list of divs. Also, there can be multiple of theses (i.e., the list could be 20 of these with random sets of 1/2 height and normal height) The end result should look like this:

[image: Final Result]

The HTML structure is:

```
<div id="issues">
    <div class="item issue">issue data 1</div>        
    <div class="item issue">issue data 2</div>            
    <div class="item bit">bit data 1</div>
    <div class="item bit">bit data 2</div>
    <div class="item issue">issue data 3</div> 
    (... can have repeating bits or issues here ...)           
</div>
```

The CSS I am currently using, which doesn't work is:

```
.item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
}
.issue {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
.bit {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
}
```

and I currently get:

[image: Current Version]

Here is the version:  http://jsfiddle.net/kSgtY/

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd never use this method, but since you:

- Can't change the markup
- Can't use javascript
- Have **Fixed heights and widths**...

You can use absolute positioning. By using the `+` adjacent selector and `:first-child` we can target the elements individually:

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kSgtY/3/)**.

The CSS I added:

```
.issues {
    position:relative;
}
.issue, .bit {
    position:absolute;  
}
.issue:first-child {
    left:330px;
}
.issue:first-child + .issue {
    left:220px;  
}
.bit {
    left:110px;
    top:110px;  
}
.issue:first-child + .issue + .bit {
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: I did add more comments, that there can be many more than the set of items listed. For example, I don't know what order they will come in. Your solution works great for the limited data.

Answer (score 1):

You should create enother DIV (issue data 5) in which you will put those 2 divs (**bit data 1** and **bit data 2**)

Comment: I don't have that option to create a second div, which is why I was asking about a solution without it. Since, I don't know ahead of time how the divs will come through. Could be 1 big one, 4 small ones, 1 big one, 3 smalls ones, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could shift the second bit using negative margins, but you have to be sure that its `height` and source order is always the same.

[jSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kSgtY/2/)

Comment: That looks promising, do you know how you could update it so it would work with any number of bits in a row, like http://jsfiddle.net/kSgtY/4/  ?

Comment: Depending on the browser support requirements this could be done in different ways. Dou you have to support IE7-8?

Comment: No, only need to support WebKit (iOS/Android)

Comment: Right now we have a modified version which has  .bit + .bit   and then another selector which has  .bit + .bit + .bit    and then keep adding them in manually. Which works, but is ugly and only works for as many bits in a row that we add the extra selectors for. Hoping there is a way to do it automatically for any number.

Comment: I've figured out that using `nth-of-type` selector won't help in this situation, as I thought in the beginning. I guess the most sensible way would be to generate the `.bit + .bit + .bit + .bit + .bit + ...` selectors with a script.

Comment: If you can edit your answer with the .bit + .bit solution, I will mark it as accepted. And yeah, we tried nth-of-type except it is element only and doesn't respect the class selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your mind and want to use **javascript**, I highly recommend [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that recommendation in other questions. Thanks again for the pointer!

Comment: Was just about to suggest the same thing, this really seems like a job for Masonry.